# Calendar view with overlays

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar

I am working on the calendar view and everthing is fine, but I need to add the overlay.
Please find the below screen shot.
[image]

Please find the below Screen shot which I have done
[image]

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: how to add the overlay in like in green color on the calendar view

Comment: I tried but I could't find any sample code for that kind of UI

Comment: I was asking any sample code, or any suggestions to solve this